# when i updateData in firestore than updateData function is not working?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, compiler-errors, flutter-test

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing updateData, NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/socialapp-aae05/databases/(default)/documents/post/113301122303110907123/userpost/4a96f3fd-6095-41bf-b8ca-ac03191c72b3, null)

Answer (score 0):

First of all we should see your code.
But it seems that you are trying to update a non exist document.
Before update any document on firebase, be sure that the document is exist.